# Does pull request in Azure devops merge the code and then runs the build definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have feature branch `feature/feature1` and `dev` branch. I created a branch policy for dev branch where I have selected a build definition.

When I initiate a pull request from `feature/feature1` to `dev` does it merge the 2 branches and then does the build? Or does it just build `feature/feature1`?

```
 * [new branch]      dev                -> origin/dev
 * [new branch]      feature/feature2   -> origin/feature/feature2
 * [new branch]      feature/test       -> origin/feature/test
 * [new branch]      master             -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      release/release-1  -> origin/release/release-1
 * [new branch]      release/release-2  -> origin/release/release-2
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/37/merge -> pull/37/merge
##[command]git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/pull/37/merge
Note: checking out 'refs/remotes/pull/37/merge'.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A pull request will always perform a merge into a temporary space in order to validate that the code in your source branch and the code in the target branch do not conflict.  If there are merge conflicts, you will be unable to complete the pull request.

If you have a pull request validation build configured, then this temporary result of the merge will also be built.  The contents of your branch are *not* built, only the result of the merge.

However this temporary merge result is discarded after checks run.

When you complete the pull request, your source branch will actually be merged into the target.

Answer (score 4):

with branch policies when you initiate a PR build it does the merge and then does the actual build

Real merge only happens on PR completion

Comment: this is completely beyond me how an absolutely legitimate answer gets 3 downvotes and no explanation why